# Jenkins: Maven can run "clean install", but not "--version"

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a Maven job in Jenkins. It can run "clean install", but not a simple "--version". It actually does output all the info from "mvn --version", but then fails with a "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException".

Anyone knows why this is failing ??

Log output:

```
[workspace] $ java -cp /home/gerrit/.jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.2.jar:/home/gerrit/.jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.0.4/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /home/gerrit/.jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.0.4 /home/gerrit/.jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.23.jar /home/gerrit/.jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.2.jar 56672
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Executing Maven:  -B -f /home/gerrit/.jenkins/jobs/<project>/workspace/pom.xml --version
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 09:44:56+0100)
Maven home: /home/gerrit/.jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.0.4
Java version: 1.7.0, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-5-xen-amd64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:100)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:66)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.cli.MavenExecutionRequestsBuilderException
    at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.getMavenExecutionRequest(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:148)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.getMavenExecutionRequest(Maven3Launcher.java:94)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:77)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli$ExitException
    at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.cli(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.getMavenExecutionRequest(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:120)
    ... 20 more
channel stopped
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
hudson.util.IOException2: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:162)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:66)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:161)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:100)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.cli.MavenExecutionRequestsBuilderException
    at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.getMavenExecutionRequest(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:148)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.getMavenExecutionRequest(Maven3Launcher.java:94)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:77)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli$ExitException
    at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.cli(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.getMavenExecutionRequest(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:120)
    ... 20 more
Build does not meet criteria for workspace archiving - result is not at least SUCCESS.
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: You think it's MAVEN problem? I see, maven installed, may be you wrong write pom.xml file?
`Executing Maven:  -B -f /home/gerrit/.jenkins/jobs/<project>/workspace/pom.xml --version
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 09:44:56+0100)
Maven home: /home/gerrit/.jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.0.4
Java version: 1.7.0, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-5-xen-amd64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"`

Comment: I do not know if it is a Maven problem. It could be some combinataion of Maven, Jenkins and the server configuration. But I can run the "mvn --version" from local cmd line without any problems, so I don't think this is a pom.xml problem.

Comment: jenkins machine - windows?

Comment: Jenkins is running on a CentOS.

Comment: try re-install maven and check on machine maven version. And check java on this machine `java --version`

Comment: Maven version can be seen from the log: 3.0.4. And java version also: 1.7.0.

Comment: try exec this action on jenkins machine on command line. After this if problem not resolve, try delete plugins on your pom file.

Comment: I appreciate your help, amisuno. I only got Maven installed under Jenkins, so going into a workspace directly from a shell and running `mvn --version` only gives `mvn command not found`. So I can't test it like that unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in jenkins and I've raised a ticket in their bug tracker:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21753

In the mean time, the only viable workaround that I've found is to use Maven 2 instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this error. I use git. I specified Git repository into root of project (http://user@github.com/project.git/PROJECT) and get a good build. 
Before I use http://user@github.com/project.git
And Build is good when I use maven 3.0.4

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I can't test and verify it as I'm no longer working on that project.